# Background image not set for React button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have 6 buttons that are being mapped, and I would like to give a background to each of the buttons.

```
button(x) {
    console.log(x.image) # Gives correct URL for image for button
    var modalButton = {
        backgroundImage: x.image
    }

    return (
        <Button style={modalButton}>Clickity Click</Button>
    )
}

render() {
    <div>
        {_(this.state.data).map((x) => this.button(x))}
    </div>
}
```

However, this isn't working. From what I'm aware, `backgroundImage` without the dash is the correct syntax here for inline CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
var modalButton = {
    backgroundImage: 'url(' + x.image + ')'
}
```

unless you have that included in the x.image variable. Providing more code will clarify this.

Comment: Totally missed it. Thanks!